# The program is running but resulting in garbage values for executive display

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
class employee
{
protected:
    char nm[30];
    float sal;
};
class manager:public employee
{
protected:
    char dep[10];
public:
    void input();
    void disp();
};
void manager::input()
{
    cout<<"enter name";
    gets(nm);
    cout<<"enter salary";
    cin>>sal;
    cout<<"enter dep";
    gets(dep);
}
void manager::disp()
{
    cout<<endl<<"manager name:"<<nm<<endl;
    cout<<"salary:"<<sal<<endl;
    cout<<"deptmt:"<<dep<<endl;
}
class executive:public manager
{
public:
    void disp();
};
void executive::disp()
{
    cout<<endl<<"executive"<<endl;
    manager::disp();
}
int main()
{
    manager m1;
    m1.input();
    executive e;
    m1.disp();
    e.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

The code appears to be running fine... but it's showing garbage values for the display of executiv, even though display and input of manager is doing well. Kindly suggest me the problem with the code.

Comment: You should add what you mean by "garbage", and what you think should be correct.

Comment: You have some very nasty fixed-size arrays, and use the evil `gets` to write into (and perhaps beyond) them. Use C++ strings, and a compiler from this century; and format the code so others can read it comfortably.

Comment: What you heard of code indentation? It is a new thing to make code readable

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `e.input()`.

Incidentally, you should usually use `std::string` rather than arrays of `char`; among the many advantages is that without an explicit constructor call, `std::string` will be a default constructed to the empty string, whereas `char[N]` will contain `N` *uninitialized* `char` values — that is, *garbage*.